# How to force Maven to download all plugins dependencies?

Tags: maven

Is there any way to force Maven to download all plugin dependencies without actually running any plugin goal?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use the [`dependency:resolve-plugins`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/resolve-plugins-mojo.html) goal for that:

> Goal that resolves all project plugins and reports and their dependencies.

Therefore, simply running

```
mvn dependency:resolve-plugins
```

will download all plugins dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that plugin!

Comment: @khmarbaise True, you got me ;)!

Comment: This really helped me, After a lot of try, my intellij wasn't able be to download dependencies but command was working and i am able to install dependencies but unless I execute any maven goal, it doesn't download required plugin and that was reason not all plugin getting installed locally & so they weren't' available to my Idea. and then error.